# Wampserver 3.0.6 64bit - 403 Forbidden

Tags: wamp, wampserver, http-status-code-403

Whatever i do, cant acces local wamp through public ip adress.
I get following error message.

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at (my public ip) Port 80**

Below i have pasted the part of httpd.cong that should regulate this.
Basically everything seems to be fine.

Wampserver is put online using its own menu item.

[image]

I have tried inserting below code into directory settings, does not help.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

What am i missing ?
Thank you.

```
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

@RiggsFolly- if you have read my question, you woul dknow it is nowhere near to the one you have marked it being duplicate with.
I was not asking why the menu item is not visible...

Comment: Looks like a file system permission issue on first glance.

Comment: care to elaborate ?

Comment: @arkascha Not on windows

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems if you have an already made virtual host file, the put online menu item does not issue the necessary changes to it.
In the vhosts file Changing **Require local** to **Require all granted** fixed the issue.
Strange....

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot F:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "F:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
```

Comment: Dont forget to remove all your other changes

Comment: thanks for saving my time.

Comment: Thank you! Finally found the answer!

Comment: it works for me

Comment: You may also wish to check the http-vhosts.conf file for your website as it may not have used the full path to the directory on your hard drive ie mine gave me this DocumentRoot "mysite" and  <Directory  "mysite/"> when it should be DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/mysite/" <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/mysite/"> hope this helps